# Code command terminal interface on macOS of Visual Studio Code not works after restart system

Tags: macos, command-line, visual-studio-code

I use the command on terminal `code file.txt` to open file with Visual Studio Code, but when I restart the system, the command stop works. And I need open Visual Studio Code, and reconfigure path to use the `code` command line interface.
How I can fix this? I'm using macOS HighSierra.

After I restart the system the command apparently fade.

```
-bash: code: command not found
```

Comment: Run `ln -fs "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" /usr/local/bin/code` in terminal once and see if that fixes the issue. Also when you say after restart it doesn't work. Does that mean the command errors out or the command doesn't open the file actually

Comment: The command works before I restart the system.

Comment: I did execute your command, but not solves.

Comment: How have you installed vscode?  Normally or through brew?  Command not found is the error you get when restart always

Comment: Normally, yes, I have tested some times, always the keyword `code file.txt` stop works.

Comment: any update/feedback on the answer I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Try to repeat again what is described in [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line).

---

> Check whether Visual Studio Code is installed in the correct folder with the command: `ls -l /usr/local/bin/code`.
>
> You can find out correct path by running the command `which code` or `where code` in bash.

If the command returns path like that: `/usr/local/bin/code -> /private/var/folders/xf/vnnm636d0k92w3sc7lm95w040000gn/T/AppTranslocation/3815E4B6-43DB-0F8E-AAB9-EDE3AC7F67CC/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code
/usr/local/bin`, it means that the program was installed in a **temporary folder**.

The path must be: `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code`.

> If the program was installed in a **temporary folder**, this could cause this problem.
>
> Drag `Visual Studio Code.app` to the `Applications` folder and repeat
>   instructions from the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_installation).

If after the above described still does not work and the program **is not installed in a temporary folder**, it is advisable to check bash settings in `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_profile`.

---

**P.S.**

Also, if none of the above does not help, you can try the following: `sudo ln -fs "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code" "/usr/local/bin/"`.

Comment: I did tried this, not works. When I restart, not more works.

Comment: What is the path returned by `which code`? Perhaps Visual Studio Code was installed in a temporary folder.

Comment: Well, I did download VS, installed, configured path inside program. So, the `code file.txt` works. I restart the system, the `code file.txt` returns: `-bash: code: command not found`

Comment: Can you write what the next command returns `ls -l /usr/local/bin/code`? This is necessary to check if the program was installed in a temporary folder.

Comment: This return: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 augustosansoncadini  admin  167 12 Abr 19:17 /usr/local/bin/code -> /private/var/folders/10/v68h2kfd6371nk0_r4hf3c2w0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/95B84B05-D7BF-4B39-8EB0-D3E089AB15AD/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code`

Comment: Drag `Visual Studio Code.app` to the `Applications` folder and repeat instructions from the [official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line). Now Visual Studio Code is installed in a temporary folder and therefore the `code` command is unavailable after the reboot.

Answer (score 0):

> So your issue may be related to how you installed `VSCode`

I would run below to install the same

```
brew cask install visual-studio-code
```

If you don't want to use brew then I would download the app from below link

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=osx

And after unzipping move it to `Applications` folder in finder.

There may be a possibility that MacOS Gatekeeper is interfering with the location of your app after every restart. Which means the `symlink` gets invalidated every restart and hence the issue

If the problem still happens after restart, you want to exclude VScode out of gatekeeper

```
spctl --add "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app"
```